# how can i make flexible list view item for various resolution in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a ListView in unity when i run in small resolution(768x1024) it works perfectly but when i run the same code in high resolution(1440x2960) it get some extra space between item and i also set all the anchors and canvas scalar property but no effect..please suggest me how can i fix that. Thanks In Advance..

picture of sample code run in (768x1024) resolution:
[image]

picture of sample code run in (1440x2960) resolution:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution is to use a Canvas Scaler component, set to Scale with screen resolution and just work pretending theres only a single resolution in the world, it works as long as the aspects are not wildly different

For a little bit more robust solution try to never specify dimensions and positions via absolute values, try to keep corners at relative 0,0, and define the dimensions using the anchors

Here's a small utility I wrote wchich is meant to speed up building the UI in that way, it doesn't handle all the cases but if you get in the habit of doing it that way you'll have less problems along the way

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class RectAnchorHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool edit;
    public bool symmetricalX;
    public bool symmetricalY;
    RectTransform rect;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float xAnchorMin;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float xAnchorMax;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float yAnchorMin;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float yAnchorMax;
    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (rect == null) rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        if (edit)
        {
            if (symmetricalX) xAnchorMax = 1 - xAnchorMin;
            if (symmetricalY) yAnchorMax = 1 - yAnchorMin;
            SetValues();
        }
        else GetValues();
    }

    void SetValues()
    {
        rect.anchorMin = new Vector2(xAnchorMin, yAnchorMin);
        rect.anchorMax = new Vector2(xAnchorMax, yAnchorMax);
    }
    void GetValues()
    {
        xAnchorMin = rect.anchorMin.x;
        xAnchorMax = rect.anchorMax.x;
        yAnchorMin = rect.anchorMin.y;
        yAnchorMax = rect.anchorMax.y;
    }

}
```

As for your list, I found the defaults are flawed, I much prefer to have children control width and height and with expand off.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But there is no effect to set the Vertical Layout Group..